# How are Firestore reads, writes and deletes counted?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm not sure if I understand Firestore reads, writes, and deletes correctly.
I think the best way I would understand is if I got clarification, correction, or answers of the total reads, writes, or deletes per action on the following questions below.
I'm using Next.js

**Q: If I add `collection` with `document` no matter how many `fields`, does it count as 1 write, or does it count how many `collection`, `documents`, and total `fields` we wrote? And is it the same logic for reading and delete?**

**Current setup for a project:**

LOGIN

I'm currently using Google sign-in provider as sign-in method.

Everytime a user logs in `useEffect` renders and `setDoc` on "Users" `collection`, user.uid `document`:

```
user: {
  //Default Firebase Authentication info
}
```

The header component(outside of layout) is then updated with:

```
user.photoURL

user.displayName
```

**Q: How many reads and writes for every time a user logs in?**

POSTS

On HomePagePosts component(inside layout) 10 recent posts are fetched from "Posts" `collection`. Every post include:

```
user.photoURL
post.title
post.description
post.createdDate
postURL.postID
```

If currently, a logged-in user created any of the 10 posts, an edit & delete button is shown.
For my question, let's say 2 of the posts were created by currently logged-in users.

**Q: How many initial reads for the 10 posts?**

CREATE POST:

When user goes to createpost page `useEffect` renders and checks if "Posts" `collection`, user.uid `document`, "Folder" `collection`.length > 0.

If Folder length not greater than 0, CreateFolder component displays, it includes:

```
folder.name

folder.type //local JSON file
```

When a folder is created its added to "Users" `collection`, user.uid `document`, "Folders" `collection`, then `useEffect` renders again.

If Folder length greater than 0, Folder component shows a list of folders.

When user creates the post `document` is added to "Posts" `collection` with:

```
post.title
post.description
post.content
postCategory.selectedFolder.type
folder.{
  folder.name
  folder.type
}
tags.{
  (lets say 2 tags)
}
```

**Q: How many reads and writes for 1 post created and 1 folder created within?**

Comment: Billing is quite simple.  Read N documents, get billed for N reads.  Write N documents, get billed for N writes.  Nothing else really matters in terms of read and write count.  Collections and thier size don't matter.  Fields don't matter.  The only other thing that matters is how much data you download total.

Comment: @DougStevenson is absolutely correct, but yeah you can reduce the counts by efficient queries. If I am not wrong, Firebase is counting read, and write operations when refreshing the console page.

Comment: @PratikButani There is not really such thing as an "efficient" query in Firestore.  They are all efficient.  If you want to reduce the cost of a query, you have to choose to limit the amount of data it returns.  That's your only option, and it's entirely up to the developer to design for that.  The costs incurred by the console are a completely different thing, but you are still paying for each individual document it reads or writes while you use it.

Comment: Absolutely, an "Efficient" query in terms of the developer writing the code. Developers should know that how they can reduce the amount of data and get the required data only every time.

Comment: @PratikButani So, what you're saying is that the *design* is what's efficient, not the query, and the developer must make good *design* decisions before making any queries.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really matter how many fields an object has, when you perform a write operation in Firestore, you'll have to pay a single write. This works only if the rules allow that write and only if the document is within the [1 MiB](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#limits) limit, otherwise will fail. The same rule applies to the reads and deletes you perform.

If you want to reduce the costs, you might be interested in reading this article:

- [How to reduce Firestore costs?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-reduce-firestore-costs-8cb712473e83)